# What is the best approach to return short units from formatDuration() in date-fns?

Tags: javascript, date-fns

I'd like to format a duration in `date-fns` `formatDuration()` function to a format similar to this:

```
10m 5s
```

However, by default the function returns it like this:

```
10 minutes 5 seconds
```

What's the nicest approach to fix this? Currently I'm using a workaround that seems a bit ugly:

```js
let duration = intervalToDuration({
    start: 0,
    end: 1295923
});
return formatDuration(duration, {
        format: ["hours", "minutes", "seconds"]
    })
    .replace(" seconds", "s")
    .replace(" second", "s")
    .replace(" minutes", "m")
    .replace(" minute", "m")
    .replace(" hours", "h")
    .replace(" hour", "h");
}
```